# ADT eclipse activate intelligence content assist for Override keyword

Tags: eclipse, overriding, adt, code-assist

All, I want to know if it is possible that showing the intelligence code of the method which can be overrided when I type the `override` keyword for a specified class in eclipse. I mean just like in the virtual studio , when I type override , the IDE will show all the methods can be override in current class,  I know I can set the ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" for the `editor/content assist` so that the IDE will showing the intelligence code for all the alphabet. But I only want to see the methods I can override for a specified class. thanks.